# How to simulate an HTTP request with no response to azure hosted App Service

Tags: c#, azure, http, asp.net-web-api, azure-web-app-service

We have an WebAPI endpoint that accepts Push notifications from a UK road traffic information service NTIS. This service broadcasts HTTP POST requests but does not take any account of responses from clients.

The service sends state-full data but if communication is interrupted can send a 'full refresh'. However the conditions it does this are described below:

> NTIS ignores the actual HTTP response from subscribers; any response
>   is considered that the subscriber has received the data. You need to
>   stop your software so that no response is received by NTIS. We then
>   “ping” the subscriber until we see the connection restored and then
>   send a full refresh

Our site is hosted as an Asp.NET webapi on Azure App Service - is there any way of simulating no response so that it will send a refresh? Even stopping an Azure App service results only in HTTP Error 503 being sent.

Comment: Anything you do here would only be a hack. Are you sure there's not an NTIS method you can call to force a full refresh?

Comment: There is no such method in NTIS and there appears to be no will to provide one either despite our requests. The only way of requesting data is to 'pull' a 2.5gb file that is published at around 2am each morning for the previous day. We need real time updates. Any hacks welcomed!